# One word for the act of being born?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there any one word for *the act of being born*?

The closest things I could think of are:

- I was born
- I come to life
- She is giving birth to me

I'm interested in knowing if there is one word to describe this; something similar to "I die."

(In Norwegian, we can use the word *fødes*).

**Context:**

I am creating a computer program, where I have several "mortal entities." These entities, amongst other methods, have a method named `Die()`, which defines everything that they do as they die. I would also like to create another method for what they do as they "bore."

Comment: I think you are looking for an *active* construction for being born. From the perspective of the mother, that would be "birthing": *She birthed a 9-pound baby boy.* From the standpoint of the infant, you'd probably have to go with "emerge": *She emerged at 10:15 EST."

Comment: Thanks, @Robusto - Although "emerge" isn't exactly what I was looking for, it could probably work in the context I am working with (defining an entity in a computer program).

Comment: Could you add some more context? "defining an entity in a computer program" ? Like defining a new variable, a new data structure or a new thread?

Comment: What does *fødes* mean exactly and etymologically?

Comment: Isn't this typically called a *constructor*?

Comment: I was waiting for that comment, Jim ^^

I'm just playing around with some class hierarchies and interfaces and, in this little experiment, I wanted these things to live outside of the class constructor/destructor.

Comment: In French, the verb 'naître' corresponds to the English 'be born'; English does not have a corresponding single-word verb. _Be born_ may be considered as a multi-word verb rather than a passive structure.

Comment: @ClintEastwood  'fødes' is a passive with an implicit agent, -s being the passive marker. Obviously it's the mother bearing and delivering the child that is the agent.

Comment: So, grammatically, "being born" is not something you *do*, it is something that *happens to you*.

Comment: I couldn't answer this. I considered a verb form of *nascent* but there is no such word in English. Inspired by the creed, I also considered *begotten*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is such a word. It is *[arrive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arrive?q=arrive)*.

> **arrive**
>
> (of a baby) be born: he will feel jealous when a new baby arrives.

[Updates]

You can consider using the word *[materialize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/materialize?showCookiePolicy=true)*  (which probably can provoke laughter and provide amusement). "*... and I materialized nine months later.*"

> **materialize**
>
> intr to become fact; actually happen ⇒ our hopes never materialized
>
> to invest or become invested with a physical shape or form
>
> to cause (a spirit, as of a dead person) to appear in material form or (of a spirit) to appear in such form
>
> intr to take shape; become tangible ⇒ after hours of discussion, the project finally began to materialize
>
> (physics) to form (material particles) from energy, as in pair production

Comment: Thanks! I think "arrive" will fit the bill, at least for now :)

Comment: @Leif You are welcome. Glad that it helps :)

Comment: I don't know about *arrive*; for example, *pop out* is just as good or better!

Comment: @jwpat7: Two of my four children _arrived_ in the conventional sense; of the other two, one was _pulled out_ (with forceps), and the other quite literally _popped out_ (caught by an attendant halfway between the birthing table and the ceramic floor). Good thing that attendant had good hands!

Answer (score 6):

Seems to me there are two problems here. One is the syntactic behavior of the [semi-deponent verb](http://magisterj.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/3/4/13349464/deponents.pdf) *bear, bore, born(e)*, which is detailed below, and the other is how to structure the methods for your game.

Though the problem may change when it is realized that

1. Being *mortal* simply means having a `Die()` method. Anything that can die is mortal. Nothing said about birth.
2. Immortal beings can have births; gods and angels and demons can be created (or pulled out of a hat, for that matter -- this is mythology and anything coherent with the story works). Thus, any method for creating rather than ending life is going to have a lot of variable context-sensitive triggers; for instance, `Create(MortalBeing-217)` has got to be different from `Create(Being-217)`, if only in terms of methods inherited.
3. `Die(Mortal-217)` is couched in terms of an intransitive verb *die* with a subject argument *Mortal-217*. But it's an active (though not volitional) verb, and, as I explain below, there just isn't an active verb for being born in English. So you can't match it.
   Instead of trying to match it, however, I'd just change the method name from an active inchoative (change-of-state) verb like *die* to a stative resultative derived adjective like ***dead*** -- which is equally true, after all -- and that matches neatly with the stative resultative derived adjective ***born***. I.e, `Born()` and `Dead()` both work.

---

As for the semi-deponency of *bear*, all that means is that its active use in the sense of birthing is pretty much limited to archaic bitransitive constructions like *She bore him ten children*.

Aside from the general use of *bear* to mean simply *carry* -- rather than specifically to mean *carry (a baby) to term*, as here -- the verb occurs almost exclusively in passive form, and in nouns and adjectives formed from the same verb root, like *birth* and *born*.

Normally we say that the mother ***gives birth (to X)***; we don't usually say she *bears X*, and that can only refer to the moment of birth if it is used. There's very little use of *bore X* in the past tense to refer to the birth; *X was born* is the idiom.

> If *bear* **is** used, it's much more likely to mean *be (still) pregnant* than it is to mean *give birth*, because of the link to *carry*, which is not inchoative.

Normally we say the child ***is born***, which can be thought of as a passive form (if you like the idea of using a semi-deponent *bear*), or as an inchoative predicate adjective, like *done* or *finished*. There's no difference in form, nor any usages that could distinguish one analysis from another.

In any event, *be born* always needs an auxiliary *be* to carry the tense, which is normally  past tense -- *X was born in 19XY* is the usual way to say it; why involve one's mother, after all?

And that means that English manages to get along perfectly fine without having neatly matching bookend verbs, by simply avoiding the active use of *bear*. This is the way things work in language -- all grammar is the result of sloppy workarounds like this; the ones that actually work get preserved as grammar rules.

Comment: Bearing children is “archaic”?

Comment: Yes; bears are kept well away from children nowadays.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, it is; it's been going on for quite a long time. Longer than English, anyway. As for _bearing children_, as I said, there are any number of fixed phrases like _child-bearing years_ that use verb forms; but no, I've never heard any woman say that she bore an infant, nor any man referring to his wife bearing children, except in consciously archaic language play.

Answer (score 4):

One word for the act of being born is *parturition*.  From the AHD:  par·tu·ri·tion; n., The act or process of giving birth; childbirth. [Late Latin . . . to be in labor. See PARTURIENT.]

Comment: I think OP is asking for "The act of **being** born", parturition is the act of **giving** birth. Same as birthed actually.

Comment: Yes, it's a good answer (because I just learned a new word from it), but I'm not sure if parturition is the word I was looking for.

Comment: This is the formal word for *delivery*, a word that is strangely absent from a 5yo question about birthing, so +1 I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question with roughly the same background [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238766/is-there-a-verb-for-to-become-born) (without knowing about this one), and the word I went with eventually was "nasce", from the noun "nascence". "Nasce" is Italian and "nascence" is English, and that was good enough for my program. "Fall" (usually applied to lambs) and "arrive" are more correct but weren't specific enough for me. "Hatch" could also be an option but in my case that was *too* specific.

Comment: +1, it's a pity that nascence is noun-only in English.

Comment: Thanks for introducing us with the word "nasce". I'd like to know what are the past and past participle forms of "nasce"? How to use them in case of past and past participle forms? Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

A small addition as you've been answered in the main:

In the context of a computer program or game, it is common to refer to newly born entities as being 'spawned', which has the added bonus of being synonymous with your original question.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

- to come to be (or: to come-to-be) [sort of an [Aristotelian term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Generation_and_Corruption).]
- to originate

Comment: Those are good suggestions, but I don't feel like they work in the context I am working with (added some more explanation to my question).

Answer (score 1):

The legal term *issue* can mean "to be born" ([Random House Dictionary, definition 29](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/issue?s=t)), but it definitely sounds awkward as an opposite to "to die".

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of *I die* would simply be *I live*. The moment of *birth* would be during [conception](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conception) when the egg is fertilised.

Comment: Doesn't something have to "bore", before it can live? Technically speaking, I guess things are already living before, and during, the time which they "bore."