# Opposite of Dying

Tags: antonyms

What single word means the opposite of dying, in other words, the "verb of becoming alive/living from the subject".

Context: Today while writing code I commented that one part of it was the "Dying" code for an object, but then I tried to comment the other part of it, the code that runs when the object is being created. Perhaps there would be an analogy to the dying ember, of say, a fire.

Opposite of dying is arguably "birth", but I feel that's wrong, probably naively due to the lack of an "ing" at the end. And may it's not the "origin" but "growing/strengthening aspect that I'm looking for in the opposite.

Comment: What part was the dying code? Was it the code that was dying, or was it code that related to something else dying?

Comment: If the code runs when the object is being created, you are obviously looking for *creation*.

Comment: You may be interested in "borning", a dialect word meaning "birth" and origin of the English word "aborning" ora-borning". I'm trying to put in a reference to the Merriam-Webster.com definition but my phone won't let me :-(

Comment: *Birthing* is an entirely acceptable word. Whether it's the best solution is less clear.

Comment: "birthing" is the act of giving birth. I'm looking for the verb, "to be born". Eg "The adult was dying whilst the baby was (being born)"

Comment: Are you talking about the *constructor* and *destructor*?

Comment: Duplicate of 'One word for the act of being born?'.

Comment: @Jim 's words are the correct terminology in object oriented programming.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I made the question clearer, and wonder if the question can be re-opened. My gut reaction was the word "thriving,"  (and I worked "backward" from that to come up with my constructs).

Comment: This is an **exact** duplicate of [One word for the act of being born](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106689/one-word-for-the-act-of-being-born), even down to the circumstances of how the question arises.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Somehow I missed the bit about the object being created. An earlier commenter mentioned *creation*, but I think what you're asking for is some sort of gerund that makes the object (in the sense you're using the word) the agent.  In that case, the object might said to be **arising**.  Some other possibilities:  **coming into being** (if you don't mind three words), **emerging**, **appearing**, **taking shape**.

My original post, with some other types of antonyms:

If someone doesn't die, he or she **survives** — assuming, I suppose, that there was a moment at which he or she didn't die.

If there was no such moment, I suppose the person is just **continuing**, though that is by no means standard usage :).  Perhaps **getting along** is more accepted, though it *is* a bit informal.  (Note that *I'm surviving* has more or less the same meaning, and that it differs from *I survived*.)

Comment: I suppose "emerging", as mentioned above, is quite elegant.