# Is there a verb for "to become born"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a simple word to use as the name of a function in a computer program that widely employs a naming metaphor. For this reason, I need a simple verb that can substitute (the instruction) "Become born."

Comment: There's no common verb, mainly because most humans do not recall being born.  (My wife's grandfather used to claim he did, but that's rare at best.)

Comment: Note that choosing identifier names is off-topic here.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for notifying me. Do you mean the entire question is off-topic because of its motivation, or just that I shouldn't have given the background I did?

Comment: @Museful Avoid mentioning program identifiers and you should be fine. Note that *bear* is the active verb, and *to be born* is its passive.  You should give an example sentence showing how you use this word.  Programming isn’t English.

Comment: What about *deliver*? Children are delivered, noun: *deliverance*.

Comment: _Born_ is an English deponent verb. It only occurs in the passive, the same way _beware_ only occurs in the infinitive. So in effect it's a predicate adjective, now spelled differently from the past participle of _bear, bore, borne_, and like all predicate adjectives, it takes _be_ (and _get,_ which is the inchoative of _be_) as an auxiliary verb, in present and past tenses, and every other intransitive construction.

Comment: to **hatch** ; animals are hatched; New ideas are hatched

Comment: Related: [Which is the correct passive construction of 'she bore him on the Christmas day'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95818/which-is-the-correct-passive-construction-of-she-bore-him-on-the-christmas-day/95845#95845).

Comment: In the programming world aren't you *instantiating*? I.e., creating an instance.

Comment: @Jim We name identifiers after what they represent in application world, or may simply use metaphors to help us keep track. In my case, I am "breeding" a population of candidate solutions to an optimization problem that has a tree-structured solution-space (a little like a family tree). Sometimes I have to tell members of the population to "die". Sometimes a parent has to "lay" an "egg", at which point the new entity is initially instantiated, and subsequently "incubated" and if given conditions are met the "egg" is told to "hatch". This analogy has improved the algorithm's readability.

Comment: @Museful very good.  Sounds like you have your answer.  Why did you accept *fall*  if you liked Mari-Lou's *hatch*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(usually for lambs) [***fall***](https://books.google.ca/books?id=TAnheeIPcAEC&pg=PA450&dq=%22to%20come%20or%20go%20as%20if%20by%20falling%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=728pVYT1K7WasQTW_ICYBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20come%20or%20go%20as%20if%20by%20falling%22&f=false) v.: to become born

Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary: Eleventh Edition
 By Merriam-Webster Inc.

Comment: Where did you get that? Fall born lambs are lambs born in autumn, later than they'd usually be, due to artificially accelerated breeding. But "fall" as a verb meaning "to be born"... it would be groovy if that's really the case!

Comment: There's a link, isn't there? :-)

Comment: Wow, that's great, thanks! By the way, links to google books don't always work for people in other regions.

Comment: That's interesting although it isn't so useful in my case since I can't use very ambiguous words given the background. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @bobro it was a google book link to a dictionary, although a direct link to a dictionary, such as [this one, def 25](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fall) seems to work for more people. (I couldn't see the google book link either, just the title of the book.) Or [this one](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall) from the online M-W.